# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Content(System.String)' 

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I read some questions here but they all can be defined as separate variables but I think mine is little bit different:

```
  var sliderRecordList = this._sliderService.GetAllAsQueryable();      
  var sliderModelList = sliderRecordList.Select(record => new SliderModel()
      {
        Id = record.Id,
        SlideName = record.SlideName,
        SlideOrder = record.SlideOrder,
        SlideUrl = record.SlideUrl,
        SlideImageUrl = Url.Content("~/Content/AhsenSliderImages/" + record.Id + ".jpg"),
        Enabled = record.Enabled
   });
```

The problem relies on where `Url.Content()` method is called. Any suggestion? I tried to remove `Url.Content()` method and didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Materalize the query first, then setup the UI concerns.

```
var sliderRecordList = this._sliderService.GetAllAsQueryable().ToList();
var sliderModelList = sliderRecordList
   .Select(record => new SliderModel
      {
        Id = record.Id,
        SlideName = record.SlideName,
        SlideOrder = record.SlideOrder,
        SlideUrl = record.SlideUrl,
        SlideImageUrl = Url.Content("~/Content/AhsenSliderImages/" + record.Id + ".jpg"),
        Enabled = record.Enabled
   });
```

`.ToList()` will execute the query first.

On a side note, consider using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to turn the above code into just a couple of lines:

```
var sliderRecordList = this._sliderService.GetAllAsQueryable().ToList();
var sliderModelList = Mapper.Map<ICollection<SliderRecord>, ICollection<SliderModel>>(sliderRecordList);
```

URL generation can be done in the View.

Comment: Well, that's what I was avoiding but it seems I don't have any other chance!

Comment: @DorianGray - Entity Framework needs to create "constants" for materializing a query. Why would you try and avoid this? It makes no difference if you materalize first, since your not filtering the query  anyway.

Comment: I am passing `sliderModelList` to some other methods and applying the filtering inside the methods depending on which methods takes the `IQueryable<>` so they can filter it before using it and get the least data amount.

Comment: @DorianGray - okay, well unless you elaborate/provide that code i can't really help much more. :) The code seems disjointed though. All your doing is projecting from one object to another, are you trying to store the MVC generated URL (SliderImageUrl) in the DB? If so, i would ask why.

Comment: I am using `IQueryable` to assign filtering task to SQL Server as you know :) so I am passing `IQueryable` around so that .NET can create a sql query for me as the `IEnumerable` will retrieve everything to the memory and then filter things out. Nope, I am not storing the URL in the database rather I am passing that info to the views once the methods are done with filtering on the `sliderModelList`.

Comment: Your solution worked BTW. Thanks for spending your time helping :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the function `Url.Content` can not translated to its SQL equivalent function. Use `AsEnumerable` function to the list and give it a try

```
var sliderModelList = sliderRecordList.AsEnumerable.Select(record => new SliderModel()
      {
        Id = record.Id,
        SlideName = record.SlideName,
        SlideOrder = record.SlideOrder,
        SlideUrl = record.SlideUrl,
        SlideImageUrl = Url.Content("~/Content/AhsenSliderImages/" + record.Id + ".jpg"),
        Enabled = record.Enabled
   });
```

Good luck.